# ServerSocket does not accept new connection/requests from clients

Tags: java, multithreading, serversocket

I have a ServerSocket that does not accept new requests from client while there's an ongoing process. I've been debugging this for quite some time now and I don't know where my error is. As far as i'm concerned I've followed all the initialization for creating new threads.

Below is my code:

```
public class CService
{
    boolean decision = false;

    public void otherConnect() throws Exception {

        synchronized (_SYNC_){ 

            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(14344, 1000);
            IsoServerBean isoServerBean = new IsoServerBean();
            log.info("Waiting for connections...");
            byte[] lenbuf = new byte[4];                    

            while(true){
                Socket clientSocket = null;          
                clientSocket = server.accept();
                int otherLen = isoServerBean.getOtherHeaderLength();
                int size = 352; 
                byte[] buf = new byte[size];

                clientSocket.getInputStream().read(buf);
                HexDump.hexDump(buf,1,size);  
                byte[] targetBuf = new byte[size-2];
                System.arraycopy(buf, 4, targetBuf, 0, size-4);
                setMyConnectionClient(clientSocket);
                new Thread(new CProcessorForClient(targetBuf, clientSocket, 4), "resp").start();  
            }
        }
    }

    private class CProcessorForClient extends Thread{

        private volatile boolean stopFlag;
        private volatile boolean stopped;            

        private byte[] msg;
        private Socket clientSocket;
        private Socket socket;
        private int millis;
        private int ctr =0;

        CProcessorForClient(byte[] buf, Socket s, int waitMillis) {
            stopFlag = false;
            stopped = false;
            msg = buf;                        
            socket = s;
            millis = waitMillis;
        }



        public void killMe()
        {
            stopFlag = true;
            synchronized (_SYNC_)
            {
            this.interrupt();
            }
        }    

        public boolean killed()
        {
            return stopped;
        }                

        public void run() {
            try {

                Thread.sleep(millis);
                log.debug("Parsing incoming: [" + new String(msg) + "]");                                

                IsoMessage request = null;
                //OMITTED THE PROCESS OF THE CREATION OF ISO TO BE THROWN TO ANOTHER SERVER
                msgFactory.print(request);
                try {
                    this.socket = getMyConnection();//Connection to another server
                    this.clientSocket = getMyConnectionClient();//Connection from client

                    request.write(socket.getOutputStream(), 0, 0);

                    int i = 0;
                    Integer sleepTime = 500;
                    Integer waitTime = 5000;
                    decision = true;
                    while(decision){
                        i = i + 1;
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                        if (i * sleepTime >= waitTime) {
                            this.clientSocket.close();
                            decision = false;
                        }
                    }

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    log.debug("IO Exception encountered: " + ex.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CService.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } 

            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                log.error("Error in parsing incoming message:", ex); 
                log.debug("ex.getMessage: " + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                log.error("Interrupted!", ex);   
            } finally{                                                      
                if (log != null) log.debug("Thread has finished processing txn.");
            }                        
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("RANDOM PRINT OUTS");
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

EDIT 1: Is it ok if I did not put the ServerSocket initialization in the main method?

EDIT 2: Updated my otherConnect() method and still same result. I transferred all processing of request inside the thread to be created and it still cannot process new request while there is an ongoing process. See below code.

```
public void otherConnect() throws Exception {

    synchronized (_SYNC_){ 

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(14344, 1000);
        IsoServerBean isoServerBean = new IsoServerBean();
        log.info("Waiting for connections...");
        byte[] lenbuf = new byte[4];                    

        while(true){
            Socket clientSocket = null;          
            clientSocket = server.accept();
            int size = 352; 
            byte[] targetBuf = new byte[size-2];
            setMyConnectionClient(clientSocket);
            new Thread(new CProcessorForClient(targetBuf, clientSocket, 4), "resp").start();  
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code for the Thread

```
private class CProcessorForClient extends Thread{
    private volatile boolean stopFlag;
    private volatile boolean stopped;            

    private byte[] msg;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private Socket socket;
    private int millis;
    private int ctr =0;

    CProcessorForClient(byte[] buf, Socket s, int waitMillis) {
        stopFlag = false;
        stopped = false;
        msg = buf;                        
        socket = s;
        millis = waitMillis;
    }



    public void killMe()
    {
        stopFlag = true;
        synchronized (_SYNC_)
        {
        this.interrupt();
        }
    }    

    public boolean killed()
    {
        return stopped;
    }                

    public void run() {
        try {

            Thread.sleep(millis);
            int isoSize = 352;
            byte[] buf = new byte[isoSize];
            socket.getInputStream().read(buf);
            HexDump.hexDump(buf,1,isoSize);
            System.arraycopy(buf, 4, msg, 0, isoSize-4);

            IsoMessage request = null;
            //OMITTED THE PROCESS OF THE CREATION OF ISO TO BE THROWN TO ANOTHER SERVER
            msgFactory.print(request);
            try {
                this.socket = getMyConnection();//Connection to another server
                this.clientSocket = getMyConnectionClient();//Connection from client

                request.write(socket.getOutputStream(), 0, 0);

                int i = 0;
                Integer sleepTime = 500;
                Integer waitTime = 5000;
                decision = true;
                while(decision){
                    i = i + 1;
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                    if (i * sleepTime >= waitTime) {
                        this.clientSocket.close();
                        decision = false;
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                log.debug("IO Exception encountered: " + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CService.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } 

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            log.error("Error in parsing incoming message:", ex); 
            log.debug("ex.getMessage: " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            log.error("Interrupted!", ex);   
        } finally{                                                      
            if (log != null) log.debug("Thread has finished processing txn.");
        }                        
    }

}
```

Comment: Move all the code that handles a new connection to its own thread. The `read` probably blocks the main thread.

Comment: @f1sh i'm kinda confused right now. when you say "Move all the code that handles a new connection to its own thread" does it mean create a separate class/file for the handling?

Comment: Yes. And you already do that. You start a new `Thread` for each connection, but only after you did plenty of operations with the connection.

Comment: `clientSocket.getInputStream().read(buf);` blocked your thread.

Comment: Still same result. Moved the .read(buf) to the thread to be created.

Comment: Not possible, Please show the current code.

Comment: May i know what is not possible?

Comment: What is not possible is your claim that you moved all the I/O into a separate thread and still your accept loop doesn't accept. There is nothing else for it to block on but `accept()`. Re your new code: 1. What is 'setMyConnectionClient()'? 2. Sleeps in networking code are pointless. Just let it block. That's what it's for. 3. `this,socket = getMyConnection()` is pointless. 4. Initializing the socket to null the line before you assign it to the result of `accept()` is pointless. 5. `interrupt()` does not interrupt `Socket` I/O. 6. Don't ignore the result of `read()`.

Comment: 1) setMyConnectionClient() is for setting the client's connection and port. So that at the end of the process i could close said connection. 3) getmyconnection() is the connection for my other server. Iso that was passed by the client is then passed to another server for processing. 6)So if message is less than the size that was passed to .read() it will block until socket is closed or message was fully read based on the aize given?